# Where should I put translate for permission in Silvanite/novatoolpermissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Hello I'm new on Laravel Nova.
I have tried to install this package for manage ACL: https://github.com/Silvanite/novatoolpermissions

Now I would like change the translate of permissions name that has default:

```
{
    "viewNova": "Access Nova",
    "viewRoles": "View Roles",
    "manageRoles": "Manage Roles",
    "assignRoles": "Assign Roles",
    "viewUsers": "View Users",
    "manageUsers": "Manage Users"
}
```

As doc says:

> This package comes with a set of default permissions to provide full
>   access control to the package's functionality. Permissions come with
>   default english translations to provide a better user experience. You
>   are free to replace these with translations in your applications json
>   translations.

And ok, but Where I should put my custom en.json for this package?

I tried to put in 
**nova-components>permissions>resources>lang>en.json**

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other Dev.

The file should be put in:

**my_project/resources/lang/en.json**